# chaining two observables in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

```
save(body) {
  let headers = new HttpHeaders()
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  return this.callWorkflowService
    .getRawDataflow()
    .pipe(
      map(data => {
        data['jobs'] = body
        return data
      })
    )
    .pipe(newData => // correspond to `return data` 
      this.httpClient
        .post(this.url, JSON.stringify(newData), { headers: headers })
        .pipe(
          map(res => {
            return res
          })
        )
    )
}
```

What I'm getting actually inside the `httpRequest` is an Observable instead of an Object. I don't understand why.

Comment: do you subscribe to your saveBody ? httpClient.post always return an observable

Comment: yes I subscribe to it in component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here when you are chaining multiple Observables you are creating a `Observable of Observables`. So you need to flatten them before you chain them. RxJS provides multiple flattening operators like `switchMap` , `mergeMap`, `concatMap` and `exhaustMap` for flattening `Observables`.

```
  save(body) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    return this.callWorkflowService.getRawDataflow().pipe(
      map(data => ({data, ...{"jobs": body}})),
      mergeMap(newData =>
        this.httpClient.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(newData), {
          headers: headers
        })
      )
    );
  }
```

This is a wonderful [article](https://medium.com/@shairez/a-super-ninja-trick-to-learn-rxjss-switchmap-mergemap-concatmap-and-exhaustmap-forever-88e178a75f1b) which talks about flattening of Observables.

Answer (score 1):

you should use switch map operator for example

```
 return this.callWorkflowService
    .getRawDataflow()
    .pipe(
      map(data => {
        data['jobs'] = body
        return data
      }),
    switchMap(() => this.httpClient
        .post(this.url, JSON.stringify(newData), { headers: headers })
        .pipe(
          map(res => {
            return res
          })
        ))
    )
```